# Translate header in woocommerce (# items and checkout)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Anyone know how to translate the header of woocommerce?

[image: Translate]

I'm thinkig of "items", "checkout" and the text in the search field...

(I installed the norwegian wooommerce and wordpress, so I havn't done any translate of my version my self)

Comment: Well...that's a small image.

Comment: Sorry, should be better now :)